# Eas unable to build react native app for android (Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin')

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, eas

I tested my app on an Android device on an emulator and physical and it runs successfully, however building the Android app is a different story.

This is the error message I eventually get. Also I'm not using expo-splash-screen and it's not in package.json.

```
[stderr]
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

Execution failed for task ':expo-splash-screen:compileReleaseKotlin'.

[stderr]

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction